# Workfront API create new sub task, dueDate is not available

Tags: workfront-api

I'm creating a new sub task via the workfront API and the `dueDate` is rejected.

I have tried:

```
[dueDate] => 2015-08-31
```

and

```
[dueDate] => 2015-08-31T18:00:00:000-0800
```

Same error each time:

```
WorkFront SubTask Results: {"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"field 'dueDate' is not available on com.attask.model.RKTask in version INTERNAL"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just spent some hours battling with the same issue.

dueDate is a derived field, once derived it can be read. It cannot be directly set. The folks at Workfront could do with documenting which fields are read-only.

The reason it's read only is because task dates will depend on task constraints and probably any dependencies.

Explore the taskConstraint field, which defines when the task will start. In a typical project management approach the start can be constrained in a number of ways including:

FIXT (Fixed Dates),
MSO (Must Start On),
MFO (Must Finish On),
ASAP (As Soon As Possible),
ALAP (As Late As Possible),
EAT (Earliest Available Time),
LAT (Latest Available Time),
SNLT (Start No Later Than),
SNET (Start No Earlier Than),
FNLT (Finish No Later Than),
FNET (Finish No Earlier Than),

So you could set a taskConstraint of MFO and a constraintDate of 2015-08-31T18:00:00:000-0800

Or a taskConstraint of MSO and a constraintDate of x and a duration of Y (defaults to days), where x + y = Due Date